# How to run cylonjs in Raspberry-pi

Tags: pi-3, rpi.gpio

I am trying to run cylon framework. I installed it using [these instructions](https://github.com/hybridgroup/cylon-raspi).

Now I am trying to execute this [sample LED blinking](https://cylonjs.com/documentation/platforms/raspberry-pi/) program.

```
var Cylon = require("cylon");

Cylon.robot({
  connections: {
    raspi: { adaptor: 'raspi' }
  },

  devices: {
    led: { driver: 'led', pin: 11 }
  },

  work: function(my) {
    every((1).second(), my.led.toggle);
  }
}).start();
```

But I have no idea how to save and execute this. My javascript knowledge is not advance one, so any help would help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some google search I found [this tutorial](http://qiita.com/okakam/items/e8d6a507c988f270fb5d) (looks like japanies)

1) Go to cylonjs installed folder

2) Create a .js file for the program (eg : blink.js)

3) Develop your javascript program for cylonjs

4) Then run

```
node blink.js
```

I am posting this for someone who may have the same problem like me.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.